# apt broken on raspbian stretch, dpkg exiting

Tags: linux, debian, python, raspberry-pi, aptitude

Trying to install mono, on my pi, apt started refusing to install packages due to dpkg exiting. The output I'm getting it this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 37, in <module>
    import apt_listchanges, DebianFiles, ALCApt, ALCConfig, ALCSeenDb
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/apt_listchanges.py", line 32, in <module>
    import email.message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.charset import Charset
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/charset.py", line 14, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/base64mime.py", line 37, in <module>
    from base64 import b64encode
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 669, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 773, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 484, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (invalid reference)
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libhunspell-1.4-0:armhf' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I can't find any fixes for this and apt doesn't work because of it, so `apt install -f` does nothing

Answer (score 2):

I used [that command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30861494/1117028) and it fixes my `apt full-upgrade`:

```
sudo find /usr -name '*.pyc' -delete
```